# Is there a way to add a JS file from a plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I would need to add a JS library (one or more files) whenever a Flutter Web plugin is used. It's possible to edit the `Index.html` of the main app to include whatever the plugin needs but it isn't automatic. There should be a way to add them automatically, maybe during the registration phase, only that I can't find the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, finally, in the `shared_preferences_web` plugin (not directly, it doesn't need libraries, but the idea was there):

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

html.document.body!.append(html.ScriptElement()
  ..src = 'assets/packages/package_name/assets/xxx.js' // ignore: unsafe_html
  ..type = 'application/javascript'
  ..defer = true);
```